# How to show different prefabs for different images in ARcore-Augmented Image scene using Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

Hi I am trying to augment different prefabs for different images say around 20 models.Currently testing with 2 models for 2 images in AugmentedImage sample scene.I have added the script AugmentedImageVisualizer.cs to each prefab.I drag and dropped the two models to the script.In the AugmenetedImageExampleController.cs I have made the following changes.

```
namespace GoogleARCore.Examples.AugmentedImage
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using GoogleARCore;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

/// <summary>
/// Controller for AugmentedImage example.
/// </summary>
public class AugmentedImageExampleController : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A prefab for visualizing an AugmentedImage.
    /// </summary>
    //  public AugmentedImageVisualizer AugmentedImageVisualizerPrefab;
    public List<AugmentedImageVisualizer> AugmentedImageVisualizerPrefab = new List<AugmentedImageVisualizer>();




    /// <summary>
    /// The overlay containing the fit to scan user guide.
    /// </summary>
    public GameObject FitToScanOverlay;

    private Dictionary<int, AugmentedImageVisualizer> m_Visualizers
        = new Dictionary<int, AugmentedImageVisualizer>();

    private List<AugmentedImage> m_TempAugmentedImages = new List<AugmentedImage>();

    /// <summary>
    /// The Unity Update method.
    /// </summary>
    public void Update()
    {


        // Exit the app when the 'back' button is pressed.
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }

        // Check that motion tracking is tracking.
        if (Session.Status != SessionStatus.Tracking)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Get updated augmented images for this frame.
        Session.GetTrackables<AugmentedImage>(m_TempAugmentedImages, TrackableQueryFilter.Updated);

        // Create visualizers and anchors for updated augmented images that are tracking and do not previously
        // have a visualizer. Remove visualizers for stopped images.
        foreach (var image in m_TempAugmentedImages)
        {
            AugmentedImageVisualizer visualizer = null;
            m_Visualizers.TryGetValue(image.DatabaseIndex, out visualizer);
            if (image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracking && visualizer == null)
            {
                // Create an anchor to ensure that ARCore keeps tracking this augmented image.
                Anchor anchor = image.CreateAnchor(image.CenterPose);
                visualizer = (AugmentedImageVisualizer)Instantiate(AugmentedImageVisualizerPrefab[image.DatabaseIndex], anchor.transform);
                visualizer.Image = image;
                m_Visualizers.Add(image.DatabaseIndex, visualizer);


            }
            else if (image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Stopped && visualizer != null)
            {
                m_Visualizers.Remove(image.DatabaseIndex);
                GameObject.Destroy(visualizer.gameObject);

            }

        }

        // Show the fit-to-scan overlay if there are no images that are Tracking.
        foreach (var visualizer in m_Visualizers.Values)
        {
            if (visualizer.Image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracking)
            {
                FitToScanOverlay.SetActive(false);
                return;
            }
        }

        FitToScanOverlay.SetActive(true);
    }
}
}
```

My unity screen looks like below
[image: Unity screen view]

Added Augmented Image Visualizer script to the prefabs to Rabbit prefab and Monkey prefab.Image given below
[image: Prefab-Inspector]

This is how it should be done?The problem once the model appears it will not disappear.So when I show the next image anther model comes on top of it.How to hide the model when the image is not tracked?

In the AugmentedImageControllerExample.cs we are using the below code.Still I dont understand why the models are not disappearing after they lost tracking of the image.

```
else if (image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Stopped && visualizer != null)
            {
                m_Visualizers.Remove(image.DatabaseIndex);
                GameObject.Destroy(visualizer.gameObject);

            }
```

AugmentedImageVisualizer.cs code given below?I have referred this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51211455/arcore-unity-augmented-images-load-different-prefabs-for-different-images/51247372?noredirect=1#comment93628811_51247372).

```
namespace GoogleARCore.Examples.AugmentedImage
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using GoogleARCore;
    using GoogleARCoreInternal;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

/// <summary>
/// Uses 4 frame corner objects to visualize an AugmentedImage.
/// </summary>
public class AugmentedImageVisualizer : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The AugmentedImage to visualize.
    /// </summary>
    public AugmentedImage Image;


    public GameObject[] Models;





    private void Start()
    {

    }



    /// <summary>
    /// A model for the lower left corner of the frame to place when an image is detected.
    /// </summary>
    // public GameObject FrameLowerLeft;

    /// <summary>
    /// A model for the lower right corner of the frame to place when an image is detected.
    /// </summary>
    // public GameObject FrameLowerRight;

    /// <summary>
    /// A model for the upper left corner of the frame to place when an image is detected.
    /// </summary>
    // public GameObject FrameUpperLeft;

    /// <summary>
    /// A model for the upper right corner of the frame to place when an image is detected.
    /// </summary>
    //  public GameObject FrameUpperRight;

    /// <summary>
    /// The Unity Update method.
    /// </summary>
    public void Update()
    {
         if (Image == null || Image.TrackingState != TrackingState.Tracking)

        {
            Models[Image.DatabaseIndex].SetActive(false);

            //Models[0].SetActive(false);
            //Models[1].SetActive(false);

            return;
        }

        if (Image == null || Image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Stopped)
            {
            Models[Image.DatabaseIndex].SetActive(false);

            //Models[0].SetActive(false);
            //Models[1].SetActive(false);

            return;

             }

        if (Image == null || Image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Paused)
        {
            Models[Image.DatabaseIndex].SetActive(false);

            //Models[0].SetActive(false);
            //Models[1].SetActive(false);

            return;

        }



        Models[Image.DatabaseIndex].SetActive(true);


    }
}
}
```

Comment: does this `if (Image != null && Image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Paused)` returns `true`. Because this is how you achieve it. You can also delete the anchor corresponding to model in your `AugmentedImageController`script. But if i were you i would create my own visualizer and visualize corresponding model based on Augmented Image `DatabaseIndex` or `name`

Comment: @AliKanat  else if (image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Stopped && visualizer != null)
                {
                    m_Visualizers.Remove(image.DatabaseIndex);
                    GameObject.Destroy(visualizer.gameObject);
                   
                } we are deleting here in the AugmentedImageController right.Still not getting

Comment: I now realized this is a similar question. You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642352/arcore-extended-imagetracking-anchoring-api-in-unity/53656523#53656523)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that in your update function you set always both models active true. But you should only set the model active you are tracking! So like said in the comment you should use the AugmentedImage [DatabseIndex](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/unity/class/GoogleARCore/AugmentedImage#classGoogleARCore_1_1AugmentedImage_1adbc17f08049dfbd618e4b89157e05117). 
For example your `Models[0]` is the model coresponding to the first Image in the Database and the `Models[1]` is coresponding to the second Image.
So instead of:

```
// Wrong code, because you're always setting both models active
Models[0].SetActive(true);
Models[1].SetActive(true);
```

you can write:

```
// Only set the tracking Image active
Models[Image.DatabaseIndex].SetActive(true);
```

Another thing is in your `if (Image != null && Image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Paused)` and `if (Image != null && Image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Stopped)` you could write a `return;` after deactivating your model, so that you quit your Update function and don't set the model active again.

Comment: if (Image == null || Image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Paused)
            {
                Models[Image.DatabaseIndex].SetActive(false);

          return;

            }                                                                                                          Models[Image.DatabaseIndex].SetActive(true);                                                                                                                                I gave code like this in the Update statement.Models appear but they do not disappear when the target image is moved away from the camera

Comment: sorry I haven't so much time at moment, maybe I can lookt at it later this week. But what I experienced, is that the TrackingState isn't updated instantly when the image isn't in view, see also: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/290

Comment: I have seen similar question on github but no correct answers. I think this is a issue which needed to be resolved

Comment: I have tested ARCORE 1.9 ......https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-show-different-prefabs-for-different-images-in-arcore-augmented-image-scene-using-unity.696899/

Answer (score 1):

**TrackingState** is not working as intended.

Try using **TrackingMethod** where ever you are using **TrackingState** . Both in **AugmentedImageExampleController** and **AugmentedImageVisualizer** scripts

**TrackingMethod** has 3 states **FullTracking**,**NotTracking**, **LastKnowPose**.

for eg: the below if statement will be

if (image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracking && visualizer == null){}

change to

if (image.**TrackingMethod** == **AugmentedImageTrackingMethod.FullTracking** && visualizer == null){}

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete working example in case some one is looking for this solution. https://github.com/darshanpv/DigiCard