# ARCore Extended ImageTracking / Anchoring API in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

The ARCore AugmentedImage example application that comes with the Unity SDK package places a picture frame around the sample images included in the sample AugmentedImageDatabase. It will place a picture frame around multiple images in the scene if they are found, and only destroy the picture frames once tracking is lost entirely.

Suppose you wanted to only display a picture frame around the image most recently recognized - and remove the frame from the previous image? Checking the TrackingState of a given image doesn't help since the tracking is extended by default without any way to turn off, and the anchor API doesn't offer any information that would help either.

I have it working by destroying the old session (and creating a new one) once the list that holds the Trackable images exceeds 1, but that leads to the app temporarily freezing up for a second before resuming.

Are there suggestions on a better way to do this?

Comment: You already have a list which holds all Augmented Images ARCOre has tracked and is called `m_TempAugmentedImages` in your `AugmentedImageController`. Why not using `m_TempAugmentedImages[m_TempAugmentedImages.Count]`?

Comment: The problem is as soon as an image is recognized, its tracking state becomes TrackingState.Tracking, even if a new image is recognized afterwards. If you use TrackableQueryFilter.New to populate m_TempAugmentedImages, you can destroy the visualizer on the previous image and only show the new one, but this doesn't work if you wanted to go back to one of the previous images.

Answer (score 2):

Okay this is not an exact solution considering the reply to this github [issue](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/290) from Google developers but it solves the issue. As i said in my comments `TrackableQueryFilter.Updated` gives you images that are updated(not just in terms of status but position etc.) in the current frame. Therefore, when i log the `m_TempAugmentedImages.Count` for 318 frames while my image is in the view of my phone and being tracked, my image is updated 18 times.

Since there is no way of knowing when image is updated and it is not happening frequently, i thought of checking if image is not updated for 3 seconds i can destroy the image. In order to do so, i added `public float TimePassed` to my `AugmentedImageVisualizer` script. Then in my `AugmentedImageController` script i added these lines to check `TimePassed` of every image that is in the Session like this:

```
        foreach (var visualizer in m_Visualizers.Values)
        {
            // if image is Updated TimePassed is assigned to zero for that image
            if (m_TempAugmentedImages.Count != 0 && visualizer.Image == m_TempAugmentedImages[0])
            {

                    visualizer.TimePassed = 0;

            }
            else
            {
                visualizer.TimePassed += Time.deltaTime;
            }

            if (visualizer.TimePassed > 3.0f)
            {
                Debug.Log("Destroy is called");
                m_Visualizers.Remove(visualizer.Image.DatabaseIndex);
                GameObject.Destroy(visualizer.gameObject);
            }              
        }
```

I built it and this way you can go back to images which are tracked before and if you are not happy about 3 seconds you can lower it as well. Good luck

Comment: What if you wanted to visualize the tracking on an image you have previously visualized (and consequently destroyed the visualizer for)? The TrackingState for that image will almost certainly not have changed from Tracking, so it would not show up in m_TempAugmentedImages as being updated.

Comment: Okay i had a chance to build and run this today. We both have a misconception. I realized today  when you use `TrackableQueryFilter.Updated` this returns only updated images in that frame. So if your image is not updated it returns nothing. However, this updated does not mean its status is updated. Probably it is related to position or understanding of the image and this does not happen frequently. I will edit the question if i can solve the issue completely

Comment: @giacomohomunculus i have solved the problem with a timer work around and edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to achieve the same scenario as of TrackingState.Tracking and TrackingState.Stopped. Its just here I've used [AugmentedImageTrackingMethod](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/unity/namespace/GoogleARCore#augmentedimagetrackingmethod).FullTracking and [AugmentedImageTrackingMethod](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/unity/namespace/GoogleARCore#augmentedimagetrackingmethod).LastKnownPose. Works fine, and tested with different images in Unity Engine.

```
foreach(AugmentedImage image in images)
    {
        var viz = GetVisualizer(image);

        //Marker is being tracked
        if(image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracking && viz == null && image.TrackingMethod == AugmentedImageTrackingMethod.FullTracking)
        {
            AddVisualizer(image);
        }
        //marker is not tracked in camera output
        else if(image.TrackingMethod == AugmentedImageTrackingMethod.LastKnownPose && viz != null)
        {
            RemoveVisualizer(image, viz);
        }
    }
```

Answer reference is from [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/augmented-images/guide).

Comment: I have updated my code please have a look......https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-show-different-prefabs-for-different-images-in-arcore-augmented-image-scene-using-unity.696899/

Answer (score 0):

5 Months later and this problem is still there, really weird from Google that they did not fix this and are ignoring such issues on Github.

I found a workaround that exploits AugmentedImageTrackingMethod, it is not very optimal, but the only thing that I found that works: in the Update method in AugmentedImageController.cs

```
 foreach (var image in m_TempAugmentedImages)
    {

        AugmentedImageVisualizerZreality visualizer = null;
        m_Visualizers.TryGetValue(image.DatabaseIndex, out visualizer);

        if (image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracking && visualizer == null)
        {
            // Create an anchor to ensure that ARCore keeps tracking this augmented image.
           // This only fires Tracking and then goes directly to paused, for ever..
            Anchor anchor = image.CreateAnchor(image.CenterPose);
            visualizer = Instantiate(
                AugmentedImageVisualizerPrefab, anchor.transform);
            visualizer.Image = image;
            m_Visualizers.Add(image.DatabaseIndex, visualizer);
        }
        else if (image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Stopped && visualizer != null)
        {
            m_Visualizers.Remove(image.DatabaseIndex);
            GameObject.Destroy(visualizer.gameObject);
        } else if (image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Paused)
        {
            trackingHint.text = "Tracking paused";
        }

        // We take care of hiding and showing here
        switch (image.TrackingMethod)
        {
            case AugmentedImageTrackingMethod.FullTracking:
                visualizer.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                trackingHint.text = "Tracking in progress..";
                break;
            case AugmentedImageTrackingMethod.LastKnownPose:
                visualizer.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                trackingHint.text = "LastKnownPose";
                break;
            case AugmentedImageTrackingMethod.NotTracking:
                trackingHint.text = "NotTracking";
                visualizer.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Not a very clean workaround, but it does the trick if you choose ARCore over vuforia..