# Augmented Images in ARCore - How to use more prefabs and to update trackables, in an easier way?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm trying to make a simple AR Images app, for students to use but, since I don't have much programming experience, I'm trying to just use and change the example files as the base for the app.

Until now, after many hours of trying, and reading about it, I still couldn't make it work with my own images and prefabs... Using AR Images should be the easiest thing in ARCore, right?

Could someone please help, by uploading a working base project, that is independent of the ARCore example files? Or at least the main scripts with these improvements:

- using several images and prefabs, like 15 or 20 max.
- an easier way, like a drag and drop prefab list, of corresponding the images number or name with the correct prefab...
- ...maybe like shown in    [ARCore + Unity + Augmented Images - Load different prefabs for different Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51211455/arcore-unity-augmented-images-load-different-prefabs-for-different-images)
- an easier way of updating trackables - their state, adding and removing prefabs when visible or they get out of sight

I have seen some answers to individual problems, but it's hard to put all that in the scripts, without messing something else... at least for me it is ;-)

I think this could help a lot more people besides me, by updating this problem and putting several answers in one place. Thank you!

Using: Unity 2019.2 beta - ARCore 1.10 for Unity